# Flexbox Layout Height Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to make a simple vertical layout structure with header, main, and footer sections. For some reason, rather than main filling the remaining space between the header and the footer, it becomes taller than expected and forces the body to scroll.

When using Chrome's dev tools to set the screen size to iPhone 12 Pro (390px x 844px), main is computed as 805.333px. When making the screen 800px x 800px, main is computed at 761.333px. #application seems to be working fine. It remains the correct height.

Not sure what I am missing here.

CSS:

```
html,
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
}
body,
body *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#application{
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    min-height: 100%;
    header,
    main,
    footer{
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }
    header,
    footer{
        //flex-shrink: 0;
    }
    header{
        
    }
    main{
        flex-grow: 1;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    footer{

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="application">
            <header>Header</header>
            <main>Main</main>
            <footer>Footer</footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I doesnt have any issues with your code, i see any overflow

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is really annoying. But someone else looking here may be helped... It wasn't ANY of the above code. It turned out to be an issue with Chrome's Dev Tools. After fighting this thing for a while, I turned off Dev tools and turned them back on and it worked. What a pain!